# Performing a modifier+click action with a touchscreen?

Tags: windows-8, touchscreen, modifier-keys

I'm using a Windows 8 touchscreen laptop and want to be able to perform modified clicks with touches. Most notably and frequently used for me is the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> action, as well as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Drag</kbd>. The actions work perfectly fine if I use them with the trackpad on the laptop, but if I use the touchscreen none of the modifiers take effect.

I was surprised to find a lack of others having the same desire after several searches. I feel like there should be an easy solution to this, however; a piece of software or a script or simple setting-change that I'm just missing.

Comment: The truth is that there isn't a simple solution for this... You can either do it via buttons on the screen, which will block certain areas to click, or you can do it via "gestures", which is problematic when you want to click a small area.